# Initialize request in get_edit_handler in ModelAdmin class in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail

I can not inilitialize request in ModelAdmin. By default, request in function `def get_edit_handler(self, instance, request)` is None. How can I do it so I can access request in the function mentioned above? E.g for request.user.

```
class SomemodelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    model = Somemodel
    list_display = ("field",)
    edit_view_class = SaveContinueEditView
    def get_edit_handler(self, instance, request):
        print(request) #This prints None.
```

UPDATE:

As cnk suggested, I tried  creating a custom Form object and doing request.user actions in its **init** method like so:

```
class SomemodelAdmin(ModelAdmin, EditHandler):
    model = Somemodel
    list_display = ("field")
    edit_view_class = SaveContinueEditView
    def get_edit_handler(self, instance, request):
        self.form_class = RequestForm(request=request) #Without request parameter I get Keyerror 'request here
```

form class

```
class RequestForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Somemodel
        fields = "__all__"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(RequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #some other code with self.request.user
```

Error I get is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user' this error is because of self.request.user in RequestForm. I also tried including get_edit_handler function in custom form, but it does not work. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and edit views use:

```
class CreateView(ModelFormView):
class EditView(ModelFormView, InstanceSpecificView):
```

Which extends:

```
class ModelFormView(WMABaseView, FormView):
```

So you can customize thes views like:

```
class SomeCreateView(CreateView)
class SomeEditView(EditView)
```

And add “setup” to them:

```
def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
    self.edit_handler = self.get_edit_handler(request)
```

Then you change your admin view like this:

```
class SomemodelAdmin(ModelAdmin, EditHandler):

    create_view_class = SomeCreateView
    edit_view_class = SomeEditView
```

In summary:
You overide the setup method in the ModelFormView by providing you own views to SomemodelAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are on Wagtail 3.

If you want access to request information, you should create a [custom Form object](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/3.0.html#api-changes-to-panels-edithandlers) and do your `request.user` actions in its `__init__` method. It looks to me like you may be able to configure that using `form_class = SomemodelForm` in your SomemodelAdmin class.

> For permission checks, you should use the new permission option on FieldPanel; for other per-request customisations to the form object, use a custom form class with an overridden **init** method. (The current user object is available from the form as self.for_user.)

Comment: Couldn't make it to work :( but I updated the code.

Comment: Sorry. What I was trying to recommend was 
```
class SomemodelAdmin(ModelAdmin, EditHandler):
    model = Somemodel
    list_display = ("field")
    form_class = RequestForm
    edit_view_class = SaveContinueEditView
```